# Trying to install citrix receiver in elementary OS

Tags: software-installation

I followed these instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo

However here are the issues being faced:

When using epiphany, my credentials fail everytime. I installed Firefox and the credential issue was resolved, however the bigger problem is I receive a SSL error 47 everytime the client launches.

Does anyone know if a)Does Citrix Receiver even work on eOS?  b)any idea how to get it working?

I swopped over from ubuntu to eOS but this may be a deal breaker for me, which is a pity as i really like eOS so far.

Thanks.

Comment: not putting this as an answer since I don't think it is exactly what you are asking for ... I need to access my work VPN thru citrix anyconnect but dont use it ... I use openconnect and it give me full access to my network ... you might want to ask if this is acceptable to your remote access security folks ... mind you .. I am an oracle DBA and primarily access linux servers .. but if i remember correctly ... I was able to use RDP to access window servers

Answer (score 0):

These instructions here worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/40723/how-do-i-install-citrix-receiver

Answer (score 0):

I change between distros quite often (usually ubuntu based). I use the .deb install file from the citrix site (x86) version for my old HP. I initially struggled to get it working but with an SSL 61error (not 41) referencing the thawte certificates.

I searched the web and found the relevant certificate files there were two (Thawte_Premium_Server_CA). I downloaded these and saved them to my storage partition and whenever I change distros I just copy the two files into the following directories (/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla and /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts). Bit of a belt and braces approach maybe but it works everytime for me and I'm currently on elementary os loki.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer! Could you add a bit of context about what this does and why it solves the issue?